# gulp.watch running only once on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm just started to use **Gulp** to improve my workflow. I'm currently have a task called `styles` that compiles `.less` files, and a task called `watch`, to watch for changes in any `.less` file and, then, run `styles` task. My `gulpfile.js` contains this code:

```
var gulp = require( 'gulp' ),
        less = require( 'gulp-less' ),
        autoprefixer = require( 'gulp-autoprefixer' ),
        minifycss = require( 'gulp-minify-css' ),
        jshint = require( 'gulp-jshint' ),
        uglify = require( 'gulp-uglify' ),
        imagemin = require( 'gulp-imagemin' ),
        rename = require( 'gulp-rename' ),
        clean = require( 'gulp-clean' ),
        concat = require( 'gulp-concat' ),
        notify = require( 'gulp-notify' ),
        cache = require( 'gulp-cache' ),
        header = require( 'gulp-header' ),
        footer = require( 'gulp-footer' );

// styles task
gulp.task( 'styles', function() {
    return gulp.src( 'src/styles/main.less' )
        .pipe( less({ paths: ['src/styles/'] }) )
        .pipe( autoprefixer( 'last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4' ) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'dist/assets/css' ) )
        .pipe( rename( 'main.min.css' ) )
        .pipe( minifycss() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'dist/assets/css' ) )
        .pipe( notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }) );
} )

(...)

// watch task
gulp.task('watch', function() {

    // Watch .less files
    gulp.watch('src/styles/**/*.less', function(event) {
        console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type + ', running tasks...');
        gulp.run('styles');
    });
});
```

The problem is, when I run `gulp watch`, it starts the task and runs the `styles` task on the first time that I change a `.less` file. After the first time, I only got the message logged (`File X was changed, running tasks...`). Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for any hint or help!

### **EDIT**

Just some information as requested: I'm running **Node.js 0.10.24** with **Gulp 3.4.0**. Here is a screenshot of the prompt output:

[image: Node Command Prompt running gulp watch task]

Comment: Please add your gulp version as well as a copy of the terminal output.

Comment: Hi, @SteveLacy! I just updated the question with the information you asked!

Comment: Thanks for adding them. It seems that there may be an issue with your 'styles' as it logges, but the gulp.run does is not invoked. It should call a `[gulp] Finished 'styles' in 347 μs`.
Example: http://i.imgur.com/yyOCpss.png 
I will ask the creator of gulp (I work with him) for farther info.

Comment: That's an info that I didn't knew, @SteveLacy! When I run manually the tasks, it just logs `[gulp] running 'task'...`, and indeed the task runs, because the files are compiled, concatenated, etc. But I never got that message showing `[gulp] Finished 'styles' in X μs`. I'm looking forward to the feedback of the gulp creator. Thanks!

Comment: I just talked to him, gulp.watch is built off gaze: https://github.com/shama/gaze, any issues with `gulp.watch` are usually to do with gaze.
Suggestion: breakout all the parts until you have just the working watch. Then add the other tasks until you have the full file. It may just be a function not been called with the styles

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After @SteveLacy suggestion to break out my task parts and check if any of them was causing the troubles, I got my **really dumb** mistake that causes the error: `gulp-notify` works only on Mac and Linux, and my OS is Windows. From the plugin description:

> Send messages to Mac Notification Center or Linux notifications (using
>   notify-send) using the node-notifier module. Can also specify custom
>   notifier (e.g. Growl notification).

Shame on me.

I follow a really good tutorial about getting started with Gulp, and `gulp-notify` was one of the plugins used on it. My mystake was not paying attention at the plugin details.

After I removed `gulp-notify` from my `gulpfile.js`, everything works as it should be, I got all the right logs and my `gulp watch` task works like a charm!

**In short:** AWAYS check a plugin compatibility with your OS.

Thanks for everybody that spent time trying to help me!

Comment: FYI: You can still use `gulp-notify`. There is a custom reporter adding Growl support. See [gulp-notify-growl](https://github.com/yannickcr/gulp-notify-growl)

Comment: Hi, @mikaelb! Thanks for the tip! I'll check it out right now!

Comment: gulp-notify now support Windows (through Growl) without a custom reporter. See https://github.com/mikaelbr/gulp-notify

Comment: Hey, @mikaelb! Thanks for the tip, I'm already using it in my project setup! Working great!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and mine was a total gulp newbie problem. If anyone is as pathetically new to gulp as I am, ensure your triggered watch functions end with a `done()`:

```
gulp.task("watch", function() {
  gulp.watch("lib/*.js, "foobar");
});

gulp.task("foobar", function(done) {
  // This task completion was omitted.
  done();
});
```

Comment: thanks, this might help me? Why is required to fire a callback for a gulp.watch task? My hypothesis is the callback needs to get fired otherwise, it won't "keep watching"...? My watch callback only gets fired once, then any subsequent changes to the filesystem don't trigger it again.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly gulp.run is deprecated in Gulp version 3.5. Try to replace `gulp.run();` with `gulp.start();` and see if that works.

Comment: Yes it does exist, check for example this link, even Gulp is using it
https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/7e7687ea40de4ffc27a52c5e4a2ce6f90c512813/gulpfile.js 

It isn't probably mentioned in documentation thought. But thanks for you down vote @SteveLacy.